# Does calling the WaitCallback(object) delegate impose local state variable usage?

Tags: c#, multithreading, .net-core, thread-local, thread-local-storage

This might be a very stupid question, but I just learned that threads do not clean up local state variables. Does that refer to only things created via the use of `Thread.AllocateDataSlot`, `Thread.AllocateNamedDataSlot` (which both of these then use `Thread.SetData` and `Thread.GetData` to respectively set/get the data.) and annotating a static field with `ThreadStaticAttribute`, or via the use of the generic `ThreadLocal` class?

The variable passed in via `WaitCallBack(object)` named `state` is a local variable, and will be cleaned up after the thread finishes, right?

And just to clarify a no-brainer: the [thread pool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.threadpool?view=net-5.0#remarks) does destroy threads, hence even though it preserves local state variables, you can't rely on their storage as the thread they are in has the potential of being destroyed? Context:

> Beginning with the .NET Framework 4, the thread pool creates and destroys worker threads in order to optimize throughput, which is defined as the number of tasks that complete per unit of time. Too few threads might not make optimal use of available resources, whereas too many threads could increase resource contention.

Comment: Question is not quite clear. When thread is finished then eventually it will be garbage collected and it's "local state" will be cleared. If you mean specifically thread pool threads then yes - after thread is returned back to pool, thread local memory storage is not cleared. That alone makes it not a good idea to use ThreadStatic etc when dealing with thread pool threads.

Comment: @Evk thank you! Yes I was asking about the thread pool specifically, as they are being re-used. The snippet in regards to the thread pool destroying threads is valid, correct? Meaning we can't rely on a thread pool thread to preserve its thread local storage, because the moment its destroyed by the thread pool, that storage is lost?

Comment: Yes, and also you have no control on which thread pool thread your code runs, so you have no idea which thread local variables, if any, are present there. You can only use them during single "run", if you are sure the code is sequential and always stays on the same thread pool. Once you left the thread pool callback - all bets are off